# Derive an upper bound for $\log(x)$

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms, taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds

A paper has given that for $x_0 > 0$,

$$
\log x \leq \frac{x}{x_0} + \log x_0 - 1.
$$

The way I tried to prove this is:

For $|t| < 1$,
\begin{align*}
\log(1 - t) = -\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{t^k}{k}
\end{align*}
We can replace $t = 1 - \frac{x}{x_0}$,
\begin{align*}
\log x - \log x_0 & = - [(1 - \frac{x}{x_0}) + \frac{1}{2}(1 - \frac{x}{x_0})^2 + ...]\\
& = -1 + \frac{x}{x_0} - [\frac{1}{2}(1 - \frac{x}{x_0})^2 + \frac{1}{3}(1 - \frac{x}{x_0})^3 + ...]\\
& = -1 + \frac{x}{x_0} - c
\end{align*}

How can we show that $c$ is positive and what's the range of $x$ (is it $0 < x < 2x_0$)?

Comment: @Gary why do you need $w > 0$ when you write down the expansion for $e^{w-1}$? I can see it when you take logs. But not sure why you need it beforehand. Also, how did you say $e^{w-1} > w$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any real $w$, by the Taylor formula with Lagrange remainder, we have
$$
e^{w - 1}  = 1 + (w - 1) + \frac{{(w - 1)^2 }}{2}e^\xi   \ge 1 + (w - 1) = w
$$
with some $\xi$ between $0$ and $w-1$. Thus, for any $w>0$, $w-1 \ge \log w$. With $w=x/x_0$, where $x$, $x_0>0$, we get
$$
\log \left( {\frac{x}{{x_0 }}} \right) \le \frac{x}{{x_0 }} - 1 \Longleftrightarrow \log x \le \frac{x}{{x_0 }} + \log x_0  - 1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a:=x/x_0 >0$, where  $x, x_0 >0$.

Want to show $\log a \le a-1.$

Recall

$\displaystyle{\int_{1}^{a}}(1/t)dt =\log a;$

1)$a\ge 1:$

$\log a = \displaystyle{\int_{1}^{a}}(1/t)dt \le \displaystyle{\int_{1}^{a}}(1)dt,$

$\log a \le a-1.$

2)$1>a>0:$

Then $\displaystyle{\int_{a}^{1}}(1/t)dt >\displaystyle{\int_{a}^{1}}(1)dt=1-a;$

$(-1)\displaystyle{\int_{a}^{1}} (1/t)dt <a-1;$

$\log a= \displaystyle{\int_{1}^{a}}(1/t)dt <a-1$, and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\log x$ is concave, so it remains below its tangent at $x_0$.